Why can my container can access the local file system in MacOS M1 using volume bind without access right?
I try to run a docker compose below in directory /Users/myuser/sql of a MacOS M1. I use Docker Desktop for the docker setup with file sharing implementation of VirtioFS.
services:
  sqlserver:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    platform: linux/amd64
    hostname: sqlserver
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: "mypassw0rd"
      MSSQL_PID: "Developer"
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    volumes:
      - ./mssql:/var/opt/mssql
    networks:
      - sqlserver-nw

networks:
  sqlserver-nw:

So, it start the container successfully. What I don't understand how come the user of container can access my local file system without setting any file permission.
I exec inside the container and run id and I get output below
$ id
uid=10001(mssql) gid=10001(mssql) groups=10001(mssql)

$ namei -l /var/opt/mssql
f: /var/opt/mssql
drwxr-xr-x root  root  /
drwxr-xr-x root  root  var
drwxr-xr-x root  root  opt
drwxr-xr-x mssql mssql mssql

When I type CLI below in my local directory, I can see output below
$ ls -ld mssql
drwxr-xr-x  6 myuser  myusergroup  192 Jul  1 12:21 mssql
$ id
uid=503(myuser) gid=20(myusergroup)

Side note: I also see file sharing setting in docker desktop contains /Users.
Could you explain to me why the user of the container can access the local file system of my MacOS M1 without proper access right?
Edit:
From the suggested duplicate question, the owner of file in container is that of the host. However, my output shows that the owner of file in the container is not the same as that of the host.
I found an issue related to permission https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/6614, but I am not sure if this is related.

Check the file sharing settings of your Mac. (System Preferences, Sharing icon)

Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61009190/596285

@BMitch, Thanks. I didn't know I am using VirtioFS by the default settings. But your suggestion is for osxfs.

@p3consulting, my file sharing of the Mac is turned off.

VirtioFS is the successor to Osxfs (it was added after that answer was created). They have similar properties for file permissions and the link takes you to a description of both now.

@BMitch, I added some output from the container. From the suggested duplicate question, the owner of file in container is that of the host. However, my output shows that the owner of file in the container is not the same as that of the host. Could you explain this?

Docker Desktop is running the docker engine inside of a Linux VM. You are not directly accessing the files on the desktop host. Instead, it goes through a layer of virtualization that intentionally maps uids and gids to avoid permission issues that most Linux users encounter.

@BMitch, what you said make sense to me, and do you know where we could find related documentation of this? Like how this mapping works in Docker Desktop.

I don't see anything in my quick search. If you can't find it on docs.docker.com, consider an issue on https://github.com/docker/docs.
